# replace blanks in the column with the values in the same column in DF based on the corresponding values in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Initial table:

```py
| Acc num  | Bank name |
| 100250-- |    NaN    |
| 100250   |    NaN    |
| 100250   |    NaN    |
| 100250   |    SBI    |
| 200100   |    NaN    | 
| 200100   |    NaN    |
| 200100   |   ICICI   |
| 200100   |    NaN    |
```

Desired output (fill the blanks in the column with the values in the same column in DF based on the corresponding values in another column in pandas):

```py
| Acc num  | Bank name |
| 100250-- |    SBI    |
| 100250   |    SBI    |
| 100250   |    SBI    |
| 100250   |    SBI    |
| 200100   |   ICICI   | 
| 200100   |   ICICI   |
| 200100   |   ICICI   |
| 200100   |   ICICI   |
```

Comment: Hi, how exactly do want to fill the blanks? Value above? Value below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `df` on column `Acc num`, and then use [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to fill the blank values with values above and below:

```py
df['Bank name'] = df.groupby('Acc num')['Bank name'].bfill().ffill()
```

Output:

```py
| Acc num  | Bank name |
| 100250   |    SBI    |
| 100250   |    SBI    |
| 100250   |    SBI    |
| 100250   |    SBI    |
| 200100   |   ICICI   | 
| 200100   |   ICICI   |
| 200100   |   ICICI   |
| 200100   |   ICICI   |
```

Comment: Hello, sorry I corrected my question.